# Typescript Exclude/Ignore (do not compile) File in rootDir

Tags: typescript, configuration, compilation, tsc, transpiler

I'm writing a TypeScript/React Web app that has the following top level directory
structure:

```
├── jest.config.ts
├── node_modules
├── package.json
├── package-lock.json
├── public
├── src
├── tsconfig.json
└── webpack.config.js
```

All TypeScript source files are contained in the `src/` directory, but I want to
ignore a single file (and potentially more in the future) from compilation/type
checking.

I'm getting an error in this file, but I don't want to use the file in the app.
I also don't want to remove the file as it's part of a module used by another app.

#### Error

```
error TS2307: Cannot find module 'x' or its corresponding type declarations.
```

Can you help me do this? Here is the `tsconfig.json` file I'm working with:

### tsconfig

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowJs": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "jsx": "react",
    "module": "es6",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "rootDir": "./src",
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": true,
    "target": "es5"
  },
  "exclude": [
    "dist/",
    "jest.config.ts",
    "webpack.config.js"
  ]
}
```

### What I Tried

I read that `exclude` directive does not work with `rootDir`, but I tried the
following anyway:

```
Add the path to the file in question to the `exclude` array.
```

That didn't work (I didn't really expect it to). So, while the file path was
still in the `exclude` array:

```
Stop using the `rootDir`, instead add `include: ["src/"]`.
```

No change, I still get an error on the file I don't want to compile.

#### From the CLI

I tried to `excludeFiles` from the command line using both the relative path
from the project's root, and from the  `rootDir` in the tsconfig.

```
tsc -w --noEmit --excludeFiles path/to/file.ts
```

Exclude the file by name only.

```
tsc -w --noEmit --excludeFiles file.ts
```

Exclude the directory of the file (path from project root & `rootDir`).:

```
tsc -w --noEmit --excludeDirectories path/to/containing/directory
```

### Search

I've also tried a plethora of Web searches, and I've searched this site.

#### @ts-ignore

The `// @ts-ignore` comment can mute the error, but I don't think this is a good solution for my use case (as this change would be committed back to the module, and in other project I would want the error to be raised).

TIA

Comment: I have the same problem: trying to exclude a single file when compiling from the cli (without tsconfig). Did you find a solution?

Comment: @lonix I have not. Those I've asked IRL, all think it's possible, but no one has an actual solution.

Comment: @Ionix, I posted a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I did to achieve the goal.

In the following example, I want to compile all files in the `src/` directory, except one (`exclude.ts`).

The set up:

```
├── node_modules
│   └── typescript
├── package.json
├── package-lock.json
├── src
│   ├── exclude.ts
│   └── include.ts
└── tsconfig.json
```

My `tsconfig.json`

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "module": "commonjs",
    "outDir": "dist",
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": true,
    "target": "es2016"
  },
  "exclude": [
    "src/exclude.ts"
  ],
  "include": [
    "src/"
  ]
}
```

This works. When I run the TypeScript compiler, I only see the `include.js` file in the `dist/` directory. I thought I tried it before (as I state in my earlier question), but I must have missed something.